# Processing Server data

Tags: delphi, tcp, server, indy

I have an Indy TCPServer that connects a device with several clients.
When device-data arrives, the server sends it to every client.
When client-data arrives, it is sent to the device. (And the device will send it to the server again (echo)).
I only process 2 bytes per cycle.
The above works perfect.

Now i want to process/save that data.
Only when data arrives via the device port, i want to 'Translate' the data.

- I need to save the data to a clientdatset.
- Then i want to take the bytes apart and compare them with som other info
- ...

The translated data is also saved in another clientdataset.

```
    unit BusServer;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,

  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Variants,

  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs,

  IdContext, IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer,

  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TBus_Server = class(TService)
    tcpBusDataServer: TIdTCPServer;
    IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
    cdsBusMonitor: TClientDataSet;
    cdsBusMonitorNr: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorDate: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorTime: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorAad: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorAgr: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorAName: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorAFct: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorOrigin: TStringField;
    cdsIncoming: TClientDataSet;
    cdsMemberState: TClientDataSet;
    cdsMemberStateMemberID: TStringField;
    cdsMemberStateState: TStringField;
    cdsMemberStateDateTime: TDateTimeField;
    cdsMemberStateTotaal: TFloatField;
    procedure tcpBusDataServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }

    functionmon: String;
    DevicePort: Integer;
    ClientPort: Integer;
    ClientLSB, ClientMSB: Byte;
    DeviceLSB, DeviceMSB: Byte;
    FunctionList: TStringList;

    procedure TranslateData;
    function CodeValue: String;

  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Bus_Server: TBus_Server;

implementation

  uses
    CodesiteLogging;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Bus_Server.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TBus_Server.CodeValue: String;
begin
  if (cdsIncoming.FieldbyName('MemberType').AsInteger = 11) or
     (cdsIncoming.FieldbyName('MemberType').AsInteger = 22)or
     (cdsIncoming.FieldbyName('MemberType').AsInteger = 33)  then
  begin
    Result := FunctionMon
  end
  else
  begin
//    TODO:
  end
end;

function TBus_Server.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DataSetName: String;
begin
  DevicePort := 10001;
  ClientPort := 10012;

  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Clear;
  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Add.Port := DevicePort;
  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Add.Port := ClientPort;
  tcpBusDataServer.Active := True;

  FunctionList := TStringList.Create;
  FunctionList.Add('Null');
  FunctionList.Add('Reset');
  FunctionList.Add('Toggle');
  FunctionList.Add('Set');
  FunctionList.Add('Misc');
  FunctionList.Add('Status');
  FunctionList.Add('Timer/Direct');
  FunctionList.Add('Value');
  FunctionList.Add('Dimmer');
  FunctionList.Add('Readout');
  FunctionList.Add('Teller');
  FunctionList.Add('System');
  FunctionList.Add('Settings');
  FunctionList.Add('Select');
  FunctionList.Add('Data');
  FunctionList.Add('Program');

  ForceDirectories('c:\Test\');
  DataSetName := 'c:\Test\BusMonitor' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', Now) + '.xml';
  if cdsBusMonitor.Active then
    cdsBusMonitor.Close;
  cdsBusMonitor.Filename := DataSetName;
  if not System.SysUtils.FileExists(DataSetName) then
  begin
    cdsBusMonitor.CreateDataSet;
    cdsBusMonitor.SaveToFile
  end;
  DataSetName := 'c:\Test\MemberState' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', Now) + '.xml';
  if cdsMemberState.Active then
    cdsMemberState.Close;
  cdsMemberState.Filename := DataSetName;
  if not System.SysUtils.FileExists(DataSetName) then
  begin
    cdsMemberState.CreateDataSet;
    cdsMemberState.SaveToFile
  end;

end;

procedure TBus_Server.tcpBusDataServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TIdContext;
  List: TList;
begin
  if AContext.Binding.Port = ClientPort then  // Client
  begin
    DeviceLSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
    DeviceMSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
    List := tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      for var i := 0 to List.count - 1 do
      begin
        Ctx := TIdContext(List[I]);
        if (Ctx <> AContext) and (Ctx.Binding.Port = DevicePort) then
        begin
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(DeviceLSB);
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(DeviceMSB);
          // Since only 1 has to be written to
          Break
        end
      end
    finally
      tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.UnlockList
    end
  end
  else
  begin
    if AContext.Binding.Port = DevicePort then  // Device
    begin
      ClientLSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
      ClientMSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
      List := tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.LockList;
      try
        for var i := 0 to List.count - 1 do
        begin
          Ctx := TIdContext(List[I]);
          if (Ctx <> AContext) and (Ctx.Binding.Port = ClientPort) then
          begin
            Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ClientLSB);
            Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ClientMSB)
          end
        end
      finally
        TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(TranslateData);
        tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.UnlockList
      end
    end
  end
end;

procedure TBus_Server.TranslateData;
const {$J+}
  LastSave: TDateTime = 0;
type
  TProgramState = (psNone,psProgram,psIgnore1,psIgnore2);
const
  ProgramState: TProgramState = psNone;
const
  ValueMode: Boolean = False;
var
  i: Integer;
  fct: Integer;
  GroupMon: Integer;
  AddressMon: Integer;
  CorrecteSettings: Boolean;
  TmpStr: String;
begin
  fct := 0;
  // Functie uit MSB halen
  if ClientMSB >= 128 then
  begin
    ClientMSB := ClientMSB - 128;
    fct := 8
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 64 then
  begin
    ClientMSB := ClientMSB - 64;
    fct := fct + 4
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 32 then
  begin
    ClientMSB := ClientMSB - 32;
    fct := fct + 2
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 16 then
  begin
    ClientMSB := ClientMSB - 16;
    fct := fct + 1
  end;
  // Variabelen voor monitor bepalen

  functionMon := FunctionList[fct];
  if cdsBusMonitor.Active then
  begin
    cdsBusMonitor.Filtered := False;
    cdsBusMonitor.Append;
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Nr').AsInteger := cdsBusMonitor.RecordCount + 1;
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('AFct').Asstring := functionMon;
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Aad').AsInteger := ClientLSB;
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Agr').AsInteger := ClientMSB;
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Time').Asstring := TimeToStr(Now);
    cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Origin').AsString := 'Van de Bus: '{ + UserPeerIP};
    cdsBusMonitor.Post;
  end;

  if ProgramState = psNone then
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('New situation...');
    try
      if cdsIncoming.Locate('Group;Address', VarArrayOf([IntToStr(DeviceMsb),IntToStr(DeviceLsb)]), []) then
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('After locate...');
        if cdsMemberState.Locate('MemberID', cdsIncoming.FieldByName('MemberID').AsString, []) then
          cdsMemberState.Edit
        else
          cdsMemberState.Append;

        if cdsMemberStateState.AsString = Codevalue then
        begin
          CodeSite.Send('New state ' + Codevalue + ' already known');
          cdsMemberState.Cancel
        end
        else
        begin
          CodeSite.Send('New state ' + Codevalue);
          cdsMemberStateState.AsString := Codevalue;
          if Codevalue.ToLower = 'reset' then
            cdsMemberStateTotaal.AsFloat := cdsMemberStateTotaal.AsFloat + (Now - cdsMemberStateDateTime.AsDateTime);
          cdsMemberStateDateTime.AsDateTime := Now;
          cdsMemberState.Post
        end
      end
      else
        CodeSite.SendError('ServerMethodsBServer.cdsIncoming Locate Fail');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        CodeSite.SendException(E);
    end
  end;

  if ((cdsBusMonitor.RecordCount mod 100) = 0) or ((Now - LastSave) > (1/24/60)) then
  begin
    LastSave := Now;
    cdsBusMonitor.MergeChangeLog;
    cdsBusMonitor.SaveToFile;
    cdsMemberState.MergeChangeLog;
    cdsMemberState.SaveToFile
  end
end;
```

In the clientdataset, i occasionally see "wrong data", meaning:
First i have a correct record, followed by a record with the same lsb and a wrong msb.
I split up the msb in the procedure(Translatedata) in a 'high nibble' and a 'low nibble'.

So now i'm trying to find out where this comes from.

As you can see in my code i call the procedure via TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(TranslateData);

- Is this te correct way?
- Could appending/posting data in a clientdataset (whilst in the serverthread) be a problem?
- Is this a timing issue?

Has anyone an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: side note: your code abuses of the try..finally, and don't protect resource: your locklist/unlocklist *should* have its own try..finally block otherwise you would fail into some deadlock

Comment: Thanks. I copied it wrong here. In the original code it's right.

Comment: Do not lock the `Contexts` list before reading data. Read the data first, then lock the list only while iterating through it. Also, you did not show the code for `TranslateData()`, what data does it actually act on? Not the data you read from the sockets, since the code you showed is not storing that data anywhere that `TranslateData` can reach. And `TIdNotify` works asynchronously, so the data is likely getting overwritten before it can be processed.

Comment: I changed the code. This is the original code with everyting but the server stripped for readability.

Comment: @Remy: 1.I suppose i have to use TIdSync.SynchronizeMethod(TranslateData)?; 2. Should/could i pass the bytes as parameters to the function?

Comment: `TIdSync` is synchronous (blocks the calling thread), `TIdNotify` is asynchronous (runs in the background). Do you want to read some data, process it, read some more data, etc in sequence? Or do you want to read some data and process it while reading more data in parallel? Either way, yes, you should pass the data as a parameter to `TranslateData`, don't store the data in global/shared variables (w/o synchronization), otherwise if multiple clients send data at the same time then they will overwrite each other's data

Comment: @Maxxx Also, you are clearly using Delphi 10.3 Rio (due to your use of inline variables). `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` have been deprecated since around Delphi 7/8, you can just use the static `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` methods instead, with anonymous procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not very thread-safe.  You are not protecting your data values from concurrent access across thread boundaries, if multiple clients send data to the server at the same time.

Also, you should not be doing all of your service initializations in the `OnCreate` event, use the `OnStart` event instead.  The `OnCreate` event is triggered whenever your `TService` object is created for any reason, which includes not only running the service, but also (un)installing the service.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
unit BusServer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs,
  IdContext, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdThreadSafe,
  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, System.SyncObjs;

type
  TBus_Server = class(TService)
    tcpBusDataServer: TIdTCPServer;
    cdsBusMonitor: TClientDataSet;
    cdsBusMonitorNr: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorDate: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorTime: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorAad: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorAgr: TIntegerField;
    cdsBusMonitorAName: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorAFct: TStringField;
    cdsBusMonitorOrigin: TStringField;
    cdsIncoming: TClientDataSet;
    cdsMemberState: TClientDataSet;
    cdsMemberStateMemberID: TStringField;
    cdsMemberStateState: TStringField;
    cdsMemberStateDateTime: TDateTimeField;
    cdsMemberStateTotaal: TFloatField;
    procedure tcpBusDataServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TObject; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TObject; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceShutdown(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }

    FunctionMon: TIdThreadSafeString;
    DevicePort: Integer;
    ClientPort: Integer;
    DeviceLSB, DeviceMSB: Byte;
    DeviceDataLock: TCriticalSection;
    FunctionList: TStringList;

    procedure TranslateData(ClientLSB, ClientMSB: Byte);
    function CodeValue: String;

  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Bus_Server: TBus_Server;

implementation

uses
  CodesiteLogging;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Bus_Server.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TBus_Server.CodeValue: String;
begin
  case cdsIncoming.FieldByName('MemberType').AsInteger of
    11, 22, 33: begin
      Result := FunctionMon.Value;
    end;
  else
    // TODO
    Result := '';
  end;
end;

function TBus_Server.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.ServiceStart(Sender: TObject; var Started: Boolean);
var
  DataSetName: String;
begin
  DevicePort := 10001;
  ClientPort := 10012;

  DeviceDataLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
  FunctionMon := TIdThreadSafeString.Create;

  FunctionList := TStringList.Create;
  FunctionList.Add('Null');
  FunctionList.Add('Reset');
  FunctionList.Add('Toggle');
  FunctionList.Add('Set');
  FunctionList.Add('Misc');
  FunctionList.Add('Status');
  FunctionList.Add('Timer/Direct');
  FunctionList.Add('Value');
  FunctionList.Add('Dimmer');
  FunctionList.Add('Readout');
  FunctionList.Add('Teller');
  FunctionList.Add('System');
  FunctionList.Add('Settings');
  FunctionList.Add('Select');
  FunctionList.Add('Data');
  FunctionList.Add('Program');

  ForceDirectories('c:\Test\');

  DataSetName := 'c:\Test\BusMonitor' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', Now) + '.xml';
  if cdsBusMonitor.Active then
    cdsBusMonitor.Close;
  cdsBusMonitor.Filename := DataSetName;
  if not System.SysUtils.FileExists(DataSetName) then
  begin
    cdsBusMonitor.CreateDataSet;
    cdsBusMonitor.SaveToFile;
  end;

  DataSetName := 'c:\Test\MemberState' + FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD', Now) + '.xml';
  if cdsMemberState.Active then
    cdsMemberState.Close;
  cdsMemberState.Filename := DataSetName;
  if not System.SysUtils.FileExists(DataSetName) then
  begin
    cdsMemberState.CreateDataSet;
    cdsMemberState.SaveToFile;
  end;

  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Clear;
  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Add.Port := DevicePort;
  tcpBusDataServer.Bindings.Add.Port := ClientPort;
  tcpBusDataServer.Active := True;

  Started := True;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.ServiceStop(Sender: TObject; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  ServiceShutdown(Sender);
  Stopped := True;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.ServiceShutdown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tcpBusDataServer.Active := False;

  cdsBusMonitor.Close;
  cdsMemberState.Close;

  DeviceDataLock.Free;
  FunctionMon.Free;
  FunctionList.Free;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.tcpBusDataServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LSB, MSB: Byte;
  List: TList;
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  LSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  MSB := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;

  if AContext.Binding.Port = ClientPort then  // Client
  begin
    DeviceDataLock.Enter;
    try
      DeviceLSB := LSB;
      DeviceMSB := MSB;
    finally
      DeviceDataLock.Leave;
    end;
    List := tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      for var i := 0 to List.count - 1 do
      begin
        Ctx := TIdContext(List[I]);
        if (Ctx <> AContext) and (Ctx.Binding.Port = DevicePort) then
        begin
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LSB);
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MSB);
          // Since only 1 has to be written to
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
    end;
  end
  else if AContext.Binding.Port = DevicePort then  // Device
  begin
    List := tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try
      for var i := 0 to List.count - 1 do
      begin
        Ctx := TIdContext(List[I]);
        if (Ctx <> AContext) and (Ctx.Binding.Port = ClientPort) then
        begin
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LSB);
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(MSB)
        end;
      end
    finally
      tcpBusDataServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          TranslateData(LSB, MSB);
        end
      );
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TBus_Server.TranslateData(ClientLSB, ClientMSB: Byte);
const {$J+}
  LastSave: TDateTime = 0;
type
  TProgramState = (psNone,psProgram,psIgnore1,psIgnore2);
const
  ProgramState: TProgramState = psNone;
const
  ValueMode: Boolean = False;
var
  i: Integer;
  fct: Integer;
  GroupMon: Integer;
  AddressMon: Integer;
  CorrecteSettings: Boolean;
  TmpFunc, TmpCodeValue: string;
  TmpDeviceLSB, TmpDeviceMSB: Byte;
begin
  fct := 0;
  // Functie uit MSB halen
  if ClientMSB >= 128 then
  begin
    Dec(ClientMSB, 128);
    fct := 8;
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 64 then
  begin
    Dec(ClientMSB, 64);
    Inc(fct, 4);
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 32 then
  begin
    Dec(ClientMSB, 32);
    Inc(fct, 2);
  end;
  if ClientMSB >= 16 then
  begin
    Dec(ClientMSB, 16);
    Inc(fct, 1);
  end;
  // Variabelen voor monitor bepalen

  TmpFunc := FunctionList[fct];
  FunctionMon.Value := TmpFunc;

  if cdsBusMonitor.Active then
  begin
    cdsBusMonitor.Filtered := False;
    cdsBusMonitor.Append;
    try
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Nr').AsInteger := cdsBusMonitor.RecordCount + 1;
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('AFct').Asstring := TmpFunc;
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Aad').AsInteger := ClientLSB;
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Agr').AsInteger := ClientMSB;
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Time').AsString := TimeToStr(Now);
      cdsBusMonitor.FieldByName('Origin').AsString := 'Van de Bus: '{ + UserPeerIP};
      cdsBusMonitor.Post;
    except
      cdsBusMonitor.Cancel;
      raise;
    end;
  end;

  if ProgramState = psNone then
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('New situation...');
    try
      DeviceDataLock.Enter;
      try
        TmpDeviceLSB := DeviceLSB;
        TmpDeviceMSB := DeviceMSB;
      finally
        DeviceDataLock.Leave;
      end;
      if cdsIncoming.Locate('Group;Address', VarArrayOf([IntToStr(TmpDeviceMSB),IntToStr(TmpDeviceLSB)]), []) then
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('After locate...');
        if cdsMemberState.Locate('MemberID', cdsIncoming.FieldByName('MemberID').AsString, []) then
          cdsMemberState.Edit
        else
          cdsMemberState.Append;
        try
          TmpCodeValue := CodeValue;
          if cdsMemberStateState.AsString = TmpCodeValue then
          begin
            CodeSite.Send('New state ' + TmpCodeValue + ' already known');
            cdsMemberState.Cancel;
          end
          else
          begin
            CodeSite.Send('New state ' + TmpCodeValue);
            cdsMemberStateState.AsString := TmpCodeValue;
            if TmpCodeValue = 'Reset' then
              cdsMemberStateTotaal.AsFloat := cdsMemberStateTotaal.AsFloat + (Now - cdsMemberStateDateTime.AsDateTime);
            cdsMemberStateDateTime.AsDateTime := Now;
            cdsMemberState.Post;
          end;
        except
          cdsMemberState.Cancel;
          raise;
        end;
      end
      else
        CodeSite.SendError('ServerMethodsBServer.cdsIncoming Locate Fail');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        CodeSite.SendException(E);
    end
  end;

  if ((cdsBusMonitor.RecordCount mod 100) = 0) or ((Now - LastSave) > (1/24/60)) then
  begin
    LastSave := Now;
    cdsBusMonitor.MergeChangeLog;
    cdsBusMonitor.SaveToFile;
    cdsMemberState.MergeChangeLog;
    cdsMemberState.SaveToFile;
  end;
end;
```